# Can not produce assembly listings during builds in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, build, esp-idf

Software and their versions under Windows 10:

```
Visual Studio Code: x64 1.80 which is the latest
ESP_IDF: 5.1
C/C++ Compiler:  riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.exe 12.2.0
```

Using VS code I  compiled C and assembler files targeted for the ESP32 C3 microprocessor. All works well.
But I would like to be able to produce assembly listings.

Now I can manually do this for each assembler file by  riscv32-esp-elf-gcc.exe -c -Wa,-a,-ad , but I would like to do this from a build by VS code for all assembly files by adding these compiler arguments.

VS code creates a file c_cpp_properties.json. Under Configurations, in that file, I added:

```
"compilerArgs": ["-Wa,-a,-ad"],   I also tried "compilerArgs": ["{default}", "-Wa,-a,-ad"],
```

but this made no difference.

After I did a clean and full build I then decided to modify the generated compile_commands.json file and included those compiler arguments. But again this made no difference.

Any help/suggestions would be grateful.

Comment: you need to adjust the `tasks.json` file,`c_cpp_properties.json` is just for intellisence

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to add compiler options to the components, in fact you add the options on a per file basis.

My original component CMakeLists.txt is:

```
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
                        "asm_funcs.S"
                INCLUDE_DIRS ".")
```

Add the followig line and compiler options are appended:

```
set_source_files_properties(asm_funcs.S PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-Wa,-a,-ad")
```

You can always verify this by seeing the listing in the build output and also in the compile_commands.json in the build directory.